# Qt translate strings from non-source files

Tags: c++, qt, translation

I have a Qt project which uses XML files. Those XML files contain human-readable text and this text should be translated by using the Qt tools (lupdate, lrelease, QtLinguist).

The question is if it is possible to generate entries in .ts file via lupdate without duplicating the strings from the XML files in a source code file by using the QT_TR_NOOP() macro and friends? Or in general, how do you translate strings in non-source files for Qt projects?

Comment: Would be nice if lupdate would accept string/context pairs instead of just files; then one could just include such things in the build system.

Comment: I found an easier way to do it. Check my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166081/can-i-use-tr-and-lupdate-on-xml-files/28168782#28168782

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We had the same problem : XML files containing human readable strings.

Our solution was to make sure that human readable strings in the XML files were easy to extract (we put them in a `LABEL` attribute) and we developped a small tool which would parse the XML files, extract the strings, generate a context (by extracting data from the XML file), and then generating a CPP header file containing a list of `QT_TR_NOOP()`.

This file was added to our project file (.pro) that was used by `lupdate`.

This solution was fine for us but we had to be very careful about two things :

- run this tool each time the content of an XML file changed.
- make sure the XML files are UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: That sounds like a universal solution, also applicable to non-XML files. I will consider something like that, thanks!

Comment: It would be nice if you posted the tool on github, that would make this answer more useful for others.

Answer (score 3):

You can translate anything you want at runtime by using tr(), as long as the .qm file has a matching translation/context. It shouldn't make any difference whether lupdate extracted it or not.

I don't know how to make lupdate to extract strings from arbitrary XML, but that doesn't mean you can't use linguist.

1. .ts files are also XML; it should be easy to make an XSLT that transforms your XML into a .ts file. If you want to target something standard instead of just Qt, lupdate(and linguist) can process also [XLIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLIFF) files.
2. you can have multiple .ts files (just call QTranslator::load more than once when setting it up)

If you really want to have it all in one file for the translator, have your XSLT copy the lupdate-generated file into its output.

As long as you use a context name that doesn't duplicate something used in the source code, this shouldn't be any different (from Qt's point of view) from the way many apps load a .qm for each DLL that has GUI.

Comment: The XSLT idea is nice, thanks! However, my project is actually more complex and users can integrate plug-ins which may contain XML files with different user-defined schemata. How would a XSLT transform now what is human-readable and what not? (I am not sure if I can/should ask users to supply their own XSLT with every XML file...)

Comment: If you don't know anything about the schema, how were you hoping that lupdate would know what to grab? You could extract all the non-whitespace text content, or even all attribute content and text nodes, but that seems likely to be a lot of junk for the translators to sift through. Maybe have the user add a special attribute on elements that specifies the context for this text, and extract only the text of such elements? something like //*[@tr:context]/text() would select such nodes.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about using some kind of convention. Your suggestions makes sense.