# Can I use tr("") and lupdate on *.xml files?

Tags: xml, qt, internationalization

This is a shot in the dark but is there a way to use somehow qt("") in an xml file? To generate the .ts files like this?:

```
lupdate myXML.xml -ts myML.ts
```

I tried this command but it doesn't work. It doesn't give me an error, it simply says that 0(zero) literals found.
I mean the documentation says something like this:

> lupdate – A tool that scans the source files for tr() and places the strings in a .ts xml file. At this point the .ts file contains only strings that are meant to be translated.

It says about a source file and doesn't stipulates what kind of file is supported, so I think it should support various types of files; but how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried it? I mean create an xml that contains a tr(), and try running lupdate.

Comment: Yes;I'll update the question in a moment

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt translate strings from non-source files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892575/qt-translate-strings-from-non-source-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution using **QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP**:

In the following xml text i do something like this:

```
<root>
   <tag>QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("context","value")</tag>
</root>
```

And when I want to fetch the value I do something like this in cpp:

```
    Q_INVOKABLE QString getTranslation(QString value){
        return QApplication::translate("context", value);
    }
```

So to sum up in a few words. I put the macro QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP in my xml file containing a context string(you can choose whatever you want) and the value that I want it to be translated. So when I do lupdate myxml.xml -ts myTs.ts it generates a ts file having the value as the source text within the context specified in the macro. After that in cpp I must create a function that dynamically takes the translation from the context.

Comment: How a macro in an xml file could be expanded? Do you strip `QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP` keyword in custom xml parser code?

Comment: I didn't use a custom xml parser. I used QDomDocument to parse the xml files. As I recall I didn't strip the keyword, I think QDomDocument knows already to interpret QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP.