# How to translate strings from external files in Qt widgets applications?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, translation

I know how usually a Qt widgets application is translated into several languages both at compile time, as well as at runtime. There is a plenty of information how to do that by marking the strings for extraction, including the [official example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlinguist-hellotr-example.html).

In this scenario though, there are no strings, but an input from an external (let's say configuration) file and the GUI is build at runtime according to its contents. Although the content of the external file is known at runtime, there are no characters in the source code corresponding to it, hence nothing could be marked for extraction.

One way to approach the problem is to prepare as many configuration files as there are supported languages. However, it would be much better to follow the usual workflow, i.e. to

- prepare the file in, let's say, English,
- export the strings to the *ts* files used by the application,
- release the translations and finally
- be able to translate the input from the file using the installed translator.

I've found some info, e.g. [here](http://Qt%20translate%20strings%20from%20non-source%20files) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166081/can-i-use-tr-and-lupdate-on-xml-files/28168782#28168782), however I am still missing a nice straightforward way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve this in a relatively convenient way:

1. Create a **.tri* (translations include) file and add it to the *HEADERS* section of your **.pro* file
2. Populate the **.tri* file with [QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP) entries corresponding to the translatable strings in your external file. As a context put the name of the class where those srtings will be used, e.g. `MainWindow`. If a string is used in several classes, add an entry for each class
3. After reading the content of the external file convert the `QString` variables to `const char *` by using `<varname>.toUtf8().data()` in order to be used as arguments of [QObject::tr()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#tr)

Now you can follow the usual workflow for translating Qt widgets applications.

Don't forget to add a new entry in the **.tri* file when a new string is added to the external file.

You can download an example from [here](https://github.com/scopchanov/SO-ExternalTranslations). Change the language in *data.json* to *en*, *de*, *es*, *pl* or *ru* before each compilation and see the result.