# How to translate variable text in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, translation

I have a difficult problem and tried too many things but in vain.
I have 4 translation files for 4 different languages, and whenever the user changes the language, I need to re-translate the UI.

Fixed text can be re-translated as follows:

```cpp
ui->BusinessNameHelpText->setText(tr("Enter the business name."));
```

However, the variable text like the action on a button can't be done this way, because it's either “Install” or “Update” for example.

I tried this code block:

```
QString action = ui->actionButton->text();
ui->retranslateUi(this);
ui->actionButton->setText(trUtf8(action.toUtf8().data()));
```

And this:

```
QString action = ui->actionButton->text();
ui->retranslateUi(this);
ui->actionButton->setText(tr(action.toUtf8().data()));
```

And this:

```
QString action = ui->actionButton->text();
ui->retranslateUi(this);
ui->actionButton->setText(tr(action.toStdString.c_str()));
```

This works for only the first time when I change language, but after that, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a post on Qt Forum which shows a problem like mine, and this [answer](https://forum.qt.io/topic/101678/qtranslator-with-dynamic-labels/3) says that it's impossible to translate dynamic text.

Comment: But your description of problem indicates you do not have dynamic text here. You have startic text which translation is incorrectly handled. That is why it works in during first change.

Comment: No, I don't say that the text is static. Look at the question title as it says VARIABLE text.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have code like

```
ui->actionButton->setText(isInstall ? tr("Install") : tr("Update"));
```

in your program. You need to run that again, in response to the language change event.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I added a new variable to represent this state.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now I get it what is actually your problem.

Problem is how you treat change text of button.
It works only when you change English to other langue. It happens since English text is equivalent to text you have used in code as identifies of translation.

When your application calls this:

```cpp
QString action = ui->actionButton->text();
```

if previously English was selected `action` will contain text which is same as identifier of translation.
if previously other langue was selected `action` will contain something else then identifier and translator is unable to find matching translation. In such case translator will return original value.

To fix just leave only `ui->retranslateUi(this);` and thrash other code and make sure your UI has all respective strings marked that they need translation.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but I can't understand your solution because of your confusion. I only need to change the text on the button. So, please edit your solution if possible.

Comment: But do you understand why your solution doesn't work? Why it works once? This should be enough to fix it. Anyway if you are using UI Desinger, you do not need handle translation of items in that UI,  `ui->retranslateUi(this);` should handle that. If not fix your UI.

Comment: How can I fix my UI? UI is fixed but my text on the button is variable.

Comment: `ui->retranslateUI(this)` is only working with fixed text like that line from the function itself: `actionButton->setText(QApplication::translate("PackageItem", "Update", nullptr));`. I tried it now and all buttons after translation has "Update" on it even if it was "Install" before language change.

Comment: You do not understand my description of problem or still didn't provide enough information in question. Did you understood my explanation with "translation identifier"? Where this value: `ui->actionButton->text()` comes from? AFAIK this should come from xml you created using UI designer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by *variable string*. For example, if strings come from an external file, which can all be listed, you can use the following answer. [How to translate strings from external files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282029/how-to-translate-strings-from-external-files-in-qt-widgets-applications)

Use the `QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP()` macro to declare to `lupdate` those strings are translatable and should appear in *.ts* file.